# Wait for asynctask but only for max 10 seconds

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask wich I call with

```
String a = ws.get();
```

So that process waits until asynctask is done.

But what I want is to wait for max 10 seconds, if asynch is not finished in that time I would like to go pass it and let it to its thing in the background.

So the flow would be:

- call async
- wait until its done but max 10s
- other code

Any idea how I would accomplish this?

EDIT:

To furder explain what I am doing.
I am printing some data on a mini bluetooth printer. 
When I press print I run a async task that prepares data to print.
And this async task calls another async task to fetch some data from internet. But I need that data before I print so I use ws.get(). BUT if internet is slow and the task needs too much time (5-10seconds), I would like to bypass the ws.get() and print anyway BUT the async task still need to run since the data I get from internet will still go to my database it just will not get printed.

Comment: You could do a `Thread.sleep(10000)` in your `doInBackground()` but then you would probably need to restart the task and not use `.get()`. But this is overall bad design. Making the user wait 10 seconds and stare at a blank screen is not good. If you explain *why* you would want to do this, maybe someone can help find a better way

Comment: The user doesent wait. Because I call that asynch in another asynch :D
The point is that my app prints some data. I call printing in asynch. But in this printing I call another async to get some data from internet. But if this data isnt here in 10s or 5s I will print without the data but I still want the async to finish.

Comment: Why do you want it to wait as when asynctask is running the main UI is not affected.

Comment: The point is that my app prints some data. I call printing in asynch. But in this printing I call another async to get some data from internet. But if this data isnt here in 10s or 5s I will print without the data but I still want the async to finish.

Comment: use a timer task with interval as 1000 and run it until 10 secods(increment a variable inside timertask and exit it when variable reach 10) and the go for printing.Leaving the assync task.

Comment: Do not use `AsyncTask`'s `get()` method - it runs in the UI thread

Comment: why even bother using an asynctask if you are using `get()` you are basically removing all the benefits of an asynctask

Comment: @EdGeorge Check my edit as to why I use get() and why it is still in the background.

Comment: @KarthikaPB Can you furder explain or give an example of how you would do that. Note that I dont want to exit async task just bypass it after some period of time